# Nuxt Onesignal push notification is not working

Tags: push-notification, nuxt.js

i did : npm install @nuxtjs/onesignal

```
modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/onesignal',
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
  ],


oneSignal: {
    init: {
      appId: '19023887-4044-4db8-90ec-9c5ff515xxx',
      allowLocalhostAsSecureOrigin: true,
      welcomeNotification: {
          disable: false
      }
    }
  },
```

issue 1:
it keeps reloading my page ....

issue 2:
no notification is coming..
issue 3: _this.$OneSignal.isPushNotificationsEnabled is not a function